# MediaPlayer sound overlaping

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have tow classes in my code;

MusicListScreen: where I made recyclerView of my tracks.
PlayeerMusicScrenn: Where I have my player to control the tracks by the MediaPlayer.

How can avoid overlapping of audios when the user switches between the songs. knowing that I have two instances of MediaPlayer, one one the 1st class and the other in second class.

1st class:

```
   @Override
                    public void onRecItemClick(TrackResponse.Results track, int position, Activity context) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayMusicScreen.class);
                        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("trackList", mainCategoryList);
                        intent.putExtra("position",position);

                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer!=null){
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                            mediaPlayer=null;
                        }
                        changeSelectedSong(position);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

2nd Class

```
     trackList= (ArrayList<TrackResponse.Results>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("trackList");
     int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
     prepareTrack(trackList.get(position));
 }

 public void prepareTrack (TrackResponse.Results trackItem) {
     String trackLink = trackItem.getAudio();

     Glide.with(this)
             .load(trackItem.getImage())
             .apply(requestOptions)
             .into(songArt);
     playButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause_btn));


     if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer!=null){
         mediaPlayer.stop();
         mediaPlayer.release();
         mediaPlayer=null;
     }
     try {
         if (trackItem.getAudio() == null) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "audio not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         } else {
             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(trackLink);
             mediaPlayer.prepare();
             mediaPlayer.start();
         }

     } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "audio not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
     handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         }
     }, 4000);




     pushPlay();
     pushPrevious();
     pushNext();

   /*  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
             if (currentItem+1 < adapterMainCategory.getItemCount()){
                 int nextSong = currentItem+1;
                 changeSelectedSong(nextSong);
                 TrackResponse.Results next = mainCategoryList.get(nextSong);
                 prepareTrack(next);

             }

             else{

                    prepareTrack(mainCategoryList.get(0));
             }
         }
     });

    */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the technical challenge of stopping the first instance before starting the second instance?  Is it because the two classes don't have references to each other?

In my (old) app, I have the MediaPlayer instance itself owned by a singleton class such that both the Activity and Service classes can get at it. If were to extend that to have two MediaPlayer instances, I'd just have the singleton own both

You could also look at [audio ducking APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus). I'm not sure if this works between media players in the same process or not.